# Django model- How to use filter through related models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was trying to build an application in Django. see my requirements. The company will have multiple branches, and staff also work for one more branches in different roles. For example, they may work in branch-A as a sales manager and branch -b as a Branch Manager, I was trying to implement that by Django Group and Permission, ( I use custom permissions instead of Group permission). Please see my model classes

```
#Branches

class Branch(models.Model):
    
    branch_code=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)    
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    delete_status=models.IntegerField(choices=BRANCH_CHOICES,default=LIVE)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)   

    
# Roles on Branch    
class BranchRole(models.Model):
    owner_branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='available_groups')
    available_group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        
   
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

class StaffUser(models.Model):    
    staff_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)    
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staffs')  
    

class RoleInBranch(models.Model):      
    branch_role=models.ForeignKey(BranchRole,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='assigned_role')
    permissions=models.ManyToManyField(Permission,related_name='allowed_staffs_in_branch')
    role_owner=models.ForeignKey(StaffUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='roles',null=True)
```

Here I am getting permission id and staff object, but I need to find all branches which are having that particular permission (for that requested staff object).

I tried this
Branch.objects.filter(available_groups__assigned_role__permissions=permission_obj,available_groups__assigned_role__role_owner=staff_obj)

please help me to find the exact solution

Comment: Branch.objects.filter(available_groups__assigned_role__permissions=permission_obj,available_groups__assigned_role__role_owner=StaffUser.objects.get(id=something))